# $model->validate() method is printing 'test'

Tags: yii

I am doing a website on **YII and PostgreSQL**. It is recurrently exiting inside `$model->validate()` method by **printing 'test'**. I have searched whole code, There is no exit code on controller , model, beforeValidate(), afterValidate(), even whole project. 
**Question**
How can i debug on such scenario. I have only access to **ftp, Netbean as IDE**, but no localhost. `How to find which file is printing exit code or do you have any idea ?`

Thank you, 
Ram

Answer (score 1):

Messages can be logged by calling either Yii::log or Yii::trace. The difference between these two methods is that the latter logs a message only when the application is in debug mode.

```
Yii::log($message, $level, $category);
Yii::trace($message, $category);
```

When logging a message, we need to specify its category and level. Category is a string in the format of xxx.yyy.zzz which resembles to the path alias. For example, if a message is logged in CController, we may use the category system.web.CController. Message level should be one of the following values:

For more details, refer [this YII Tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging)

Comment: ah, i will again make a few more effort with these things, and append my experience here.